# Conservation of Energy as Applied to Point Charges

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation, charge

The following question appears to be extremely straight forward, but I can't seem to be able to obtain the correct answer.

The question is:

> A charge Q1 = 1.3uC is at rest and is located 2.3 cm away from another
> fixed charge Q2 = 1.6uC. The first charge is then released. Calculate
> the kinetic energy of charge Q1 when it is 5.7 cm away from charge Q2.

My solution is as follows:

> Let  r = 0.023 m r' = 0.057 m
>
> PE + KE = PE' + KE'
>
> But, KE = 0, so:
>
> KE' = PE' - PE
>
> KE' = (Q1$\times$V1) - (Q1$\times$V1')
>
> KE' = (Q1 $\times \frac{k \times Q2}{r}$) - (Q1 $\times \frac{k \times Q2}{r'}$)
>
> KE' = 0.49 J

I've tried many times to check my substitutions and unit conversions and the answer still remains incorrect. It may be possible that I'm completely using the wrong method. Can anyone please make any suggestions or corrections?

Comment: How do you know your answer is incorrect?

Comment: I'm working on an on-line practice worksheet. It tells me if the answer is correct or incorrect.

Comment: What's its tolerance? That is, how close do you have to get to the actual correct answer for the computer to call it correct?

Comment: I'm not sure about tolerance, but I know that it gives a warning or won't take an answer if the sig figs isn't considered.

Comment: Yea I just calculated it myself and got 0.48482049... J Perhaps the problem doesn't intend for you to keep charge Q2 fixed after Q1 is released?

Comment: Is it possible that I'm overlooking something in my method?

Comment: Alright. But I'm not really sure how charge Q2 would change when charge Q1 is moved away? Could you please explain?

Comment: Is the text quoted in your question the complete and exact text of the actual problem? If so, then Q2 wouldn't move because the problem as you've written it here does specify that it's fixed.

Comment: @joshphysics keep in mind that you shouldn't give away complete (or final) answers to homework questions.

Comment: yeah...this is the entire and exact text of the problem. So I gess Q2 HAS to stay the same them.

Comment: Do you have any more hits / suggestions that I could try to solve this problem @DavidZaslavsky? Is my method correct or am I over looking something?

Comment: Except for the problem with the rounding, no.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Yes I understand.  In this case was I negligent?  Vanessa seems to have the physics down and even wrote an answer of 0.49J, and you had suggested that there could be a tolerance issue which is why I made my comment.

Comment: @joshphysics well, don't consider yourself to have gotten in trouble ;-) But in a case like this I think it's best to just say the result is slightly off without mentioning an actual number. An unscrupulous student could just copy and paste the value you've given into the computer, which means they don't put in the work to learn about significant figures and rounding. Granted, that's not about actual physics content, but IMO it still runs counter to the spirit of our homework policy.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky All right that's reasonable.  I'll attempt to be more careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is just a little bit off in the last digit, probably due to incorrect rounding. So I would suggest going back and checking the calculation, perhaps including some more significant figures in certain values.

If that doesn't make a difference, then check with your instructor. It's possible that the computer system has the wrong answer programmed into it. This is quite rare but not entirely unprecedented.

Comment: Yep! You were right. The computer was expecting 3 significant figures even though the values given in the question had only 2. Thanks so much for everything! :D

Answer (score 0):

No your answer is incorrect since some amount of energy will be lose in the form of Electromagnetic radiation as the moving charge would accelerate (according to Maxwell's theory)

Comment: Your answer is physically correct, however you are missing an important issue. The  question already got an answer which was judged correct by the OP, since it allowed her to agree with the official solution of the problem. Homework problems sometimes introduce approximations in the real world to concentrate on a particular topic. However, before claiming that the official answer is incorrect, you should provide a quantitative  estimate of the energy of the resulting em radiation. You might be surprised by the result.

Comment: A final suggestion. Homework-like questions are not welcome on this site (see the policy on questions). Answering to them is not a good idea, even if they are quite old, like in this case. At some time, question and answers could be deleted.